# Function all of a sudden return a complete path with the dir name in front?

Tags: php, hyperlink, base-url

I have a weird problem. I am making kinda my own framework like codeigniter and i have made a function equal to CI's "base_url()" which in my case returns a string like: "http://www.example.com/". My problem (which i have never heard off before) lies when I use my base_url() function to make links to css files and other navigation. So when I, in a view writes:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?= base_url(); ?>css/style.css" />
```

the actual link should be:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.example.com/css/style.css" />
```

My problem now is that the "string" returned from the function is correct when i look at the source code in Chrome and Firefox. But when i hover my mouse over it, the link, links to the following url instead:

> http://example.com/%EF%BB%BFhttp://www.example.com/css/style.css

Can anyone explain why it would do this?

EDIT:
Im so sorry i forgat the source code for base_url():

```
function base_url($url_arguments = array()){
  // Require config fil
  include(dirname(__FILE__).'/../system/config.php');

  // Generate link
  $return_url = $config['base_url']; // http://www.example.com/
  if(count($url_arguments) > 0){
    $return_url .= "?";
    foreach($url_arguments as $get => $value){
      $return_url .= $get."=".$value.'&';
    }
    preg_match("/(.+?)&$/i", $return_url, $matches);
    $return_url = $matches[1];
  }
  // Return link
  return ($return_url);
}
```

Extra: my co-worker found in VIM that a tag named `<feff>` is appended in front of the link?

Comment: And the source code of your `base_url()` function is... where exactly?

Comment: Agreed, I'd like to see the code of the base_url function. Could also be an encoding problem.

Comment: Im so sorry. Went a little fast since im really frustrated with this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EFBBBF is the UTF-8 [byte order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark). One has slipped into your config variable somehow. Edit the config file and remove it. If you're reading the variable from a file and it's legitimate for it to be there, trim it off in code.

Comment: @Thor A. Pedersen try saving the file as UTF-8 without BOM

Comment: I just wound out my self and fixed the charset to UTF-8 without BOM in Notepad++ (which is my editor). This fixed the problem.... Oh my god what a mess charset can give a web programmer :O

Answer (score 0):

I would write that function as this:

```
function base_url ($url_arguments = array()) {

  // Require config file
  include(dirname(__FILE__).'/../system/config.php');

  // Generate link
  $return_url = $config['base_url'];

  // Add query string, if any
  if (count($url_arguments)) {
    if (function_exists('http_build_query')) {
      $return_url .= "?".http_build_query($url_arguments);
    } else {
      $qStr = array();
      foreach($url_arguments as $key => $value) {
        $qStr[] = url_encode($key)."=".urlencode($value);
      }
      $return_url .= "?".implode('&',$url_arguments);
    }
  }

  // Return link
  return $return_url;

}
```

Note the loss of the pointless regex - I suspect this is what was somehow causing your problem. You could have done this as simply `$return_url = rtrim($return_url,'&');`.

Comment: For the record, base_url() is a native CodeIgniter's function. Agree with your suggestion, though

Comment: @DamienPirsy I know, but the question stipulates `I am making kinda my own framework like codeigniter`, not `I am using codeigniter` - it is incorrectly tagged.

Comment: Uhm, you're right, I didn't read that sentence and the tag misguided me. Thanks for clearing this out

Comment: Thanks. I tried it out and your function works great. But again my links are still toying with me and i don't suspect my or your function to be the problem. I think it has something to do with the charset since the script appends <feff>.